# Setting up Artifactory in Visual Studio fails with 403

Tags: visual-studio, artifactory

I am trying to connect Visual Studio to our Artifactory repo for NuGet. I have successfully connected Rider, but VS remains elusive.

It doesn't just fail, mind you: Visual Studio hammers JFrog with auth requests (that get a 403) until my AD account gets locked out.

So it is a bit frustrating to debug/troubleshoot.

Comment: It is giving 403 (forbidden) which means you do not have permission to work with the Nuget repository. Basic thing to check here is to go to your user and check the permissions if the repo is included?

Comment: The OP indicates I have correct credentials "I have successfully connected Rider."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the Windows Credential Manager had a bad password stored. Editing the password there fixed the issue.

Credentials Key is "VSCredentials_{Organization}.jfrog.io.

Answer (score 0):

We had to change the password in Windows Credentials Manager to one that had no special characters (!"£$ etc.) and only used alphanumerics.

Not all special characters cause the issue (@ seems ok), but at least one or a combination just breaks it and locks your account.